# output swfobject in html

Tags: javascript, html, swfobject

Can anyone help me with the following thing.
I want to print the sfwobject into html.

Javascript:

```
var swf = domain + "Main.swf?" + (new Date()).valueOf().toString(16);
function load()
{
    swfobject.embedSWF(
    swf, "Main",
    "100%", "100%",
    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
       flashvars, params, attributes);

}
```

example how it should look after printing the inside from load()

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="Main" data="domain_etc" width="100%" height="100%" style="visibility: visible;"></object>
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: One obvious way is outputting the `<object>` tag with JS and just insert the variable into the quotes

Comment: How can I do that, pyro?

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript,

first write line below, and write rest of code in function load().

```
document.getElementById("Main").data = swf;
```